# Github pages won't find a specific page

Tags: github, github-pages

I have been using [github pages for demos](http://kdemos.github.io) for a while and everything has been working fine. Today, I wanted to host the demo of my [angular app](http://github.com/kamranahmedse/angudo) so just like my other demos, I put the starter file (named angudo.html) at the root of repository. But for some reason I am **not able to access the file at http://kdemos.github.io/angudo.html**. However, as I said, I am **able to access the other files for example http://kdemos.github.io/jquery-toast-plugin.html** is working fine.

Can anybody see what's the problem here? Why I am not able to access `angudo.html` while I am able to access `jquery-toast-plugin.html` through my URL. You can check the files at https://github.com/kdemos/kdemos.github.io

Answer (score 0):

As your angudo is a [project page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages), put your `angudo` repository on a `gh-page` branch and you will get it at `http://kdemos.github.io/angudo/`